# Installing Git on Server

Tags: git, version-control

I have recently installed Laravel on my Webserver. I intend on starting a project and I want to implement some version control in it. My current plan is to install Git on the server, create a new project and link it to git. My question is, how would I start to develop? 
Is the method I'm thinking off correct? 
Is it possible to hook it up to the desktop version of git? 
Sorry, I'm quite confused.

Comment: is your webserver on your development machine or you have a separate machine for deployment and development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use git to do version control for Laravel projects. You can configure a **git server**, or manage the project on **third party hosted options**, such as github, bitbucket etc.

- **Git server:** you need to spend some time on mantaining/managing the server. To start config git server, you can refer [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).
- **Third party hosted options:** It’s easy to use. For public repo, everyone can reach for projects. For private repo, you need to pay for it (bitbucket is free and github is not).

The way you plan to is to setup a git server. detail steps as below:

```
# in a certain directory, create a remote repo
mkdir project1
cd project1
git init --bare

# works on local
git clone <URL for project1>
git add filename
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

The way to use github:

**1.** Create an empty repo on git repo.

**2.** use git bash in the project1 folder, the commands used as below:

```
git init
git remote add origin <URL for the github repo>
git add .
git commit -m 'add all files'
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! How can I link somethin like GitHub to my server?

Comment: I add the way to use github in my answer, you can have a try.